# How to split date from datetime in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have write below the code.I try to split date and time but I can't get correct solution. I write the service in Node JS. If i try get date between dates, It is working. But if i try to fetch exact date, it is not working.

```js
exports.screenLog = function(req,res){
console.log(req.query);
Timesheet.find({userId: req.params.id,startTime: $match:{$gte : new Date(req.query.startTime),$lte: new Date(req.query.endTime)}}, function (err, timesheet) { 
console.log(timesheet); 
  var timesheetIdArray = timesheet.map(function(ele){return ele._id});

  Screenshot.find()
  .where('timesheetId')
  .in(timesheetIdArray)
  .exec(function(err,data){
    //console.log('ScreenData:',data);
     if(err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    
    res.send(data);
  });
  
});
```

```html
This is My input format below:
[
    {
        "_id": "5963653e6b43611240189ea2",
        "timesheetId": "595f4f2ec456a422bc291169",
        "imageUrl": "/images/2017-07-10_05_00_06_PM.jpg",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdTime": "2017-07-07T09:06:54.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5964bef37302792b0864009e",
        "timesheetId": "595f4f2ec456a422bc291169",
        "imageUrl": "/images/2017-07-11_05_35_07_PM.jpg",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdTime": "2017-07-11T12:05:07.687Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5964bf897302792b086400ad",
        "timesheetId": "595f4f2ec456a422bc291169",
        "imageUrl": "/images/2017-07-11_05_37_37_PM.jpg",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdTime": "2017-07-11T12:07:37.446Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5964ddf0ee77e90288d26eec",
        "timesheetId": "5964ddf0ee77e90288d26eeb",
        "imageUrl": "/images/2017-07-11_07_47_20_PM.jpg",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdTime": "2017-07-11T14:17:20.651Z"
    }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Date and Time Can't be Split in MongoDB.They are Store in Date object in database.

But You can Compare the dates By `$gte,$lte,$eq` etc.

For the Comparisons you can Only Compare with UTC date ,For this You can find out [**moment**](https://momentjs.com/docs/) Library

**eg** : date:{  $gte : moment(YOUR_DATE_IN_STRING) }

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with Node.Js, but I think the project aggregation may help you out here:

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate(
[
    {
    $project:
            {
                year: { $year: "$MyDateField" },
        month: { $month: "$MyDateField" },
        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$MyDateField" },
        hour: { $hour: "$MyDateField" },
        minutes: { $minute: "$MyDateField" },
        seconds: { $second: "$MyDateField" },
        milliseconds: { $millisecond: "$MyDateField" },
        dayOfYear: { $dayOfYear: "$MyDateField" },
        dayOfWeek: { $dayOfWeek: "$MyDateField" },
        week: { $week: "$MyDateField" }
            }
        }
]
```

)

That will return this:

```
{
     "_id" : "5897697667f26827dc9c9028",
    "year" : 2017,
    "month" : 2,
    "day" : 5,
    "hour" : 18,
    "minutes" : 5,
    "seconds" : 41,
    "milliseconds" : 822,
    "dayOfYear" : 36,
    "dayOfWeek" : 1,
    "week" : 6
}
```

Is that getting you any closer to a solution?

Comment: I think this will provide me the all the stats by NOT adding 5Hours 30Min in it because the the date which is present in it is UTC

Answer (score 0):

You can do smth like this in mongo shell:

```
db.foo_collection.aggregate([
  {'$addFields': {
    'extracted_date': {'$dateFromParts': {
      'year': {'$year': "$some_datetime_field"}, 
      'month': {'$month': "$some_datetime_field"}, 
      'day': {'$dayOfMonth': "$some_datetime_field"}
    }}
  }},
  {'$match': {'$extracted_date': ...}}
])
```

This query extracts date from datetime field and then applies some filter expression on this date.